# Timer is not running as expected

Tags: javascript, timer

In my tank game (not unlike awesome tanks for reference) I have created a timer for my bullet but when run it has a runtime error saying that AItimer is not defined. Im confused since i have another timer which in the same program but does not have this error.

```
function aiStartTimer()
{
    if(shoot == 0)
    {
        //creates aitimer variable
        AItimer = setInterval("aiFireBullet()",100);
        shoot = 1*1;
    }
    else if(shoot == 1)
    {
        clearInterval(AItimer);
        shoot = 0 * 1;
    }
}

function StartTimer()
{
    if(onOff == 0)
    {
        //creates timer variable
        timer = setInterval("FireBullet()",100);
        onOff = 1*1;
    }
    else if(onOff == 1)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        onOff = 0 * 1;
    }
```

}

here is a fiddile https://jsfiddle.net/tm9oL74r/

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function definition in argument of `setTimeout`, not a string.
Replace `AItimer = setInterval("aiFireBullet()", 100);` by `AItimer = setInterval(aiFireBullet, 100);` and it should work.